# When two monitors are connected black screen shown after boot

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have an nvidia card & I'm using xserver. When I connect a single monitor it works fine. When I connect a second monitor after already on desktop, it does not display in monitor settings. When I have both connected during boot, I get black screen after. `$ xrandr -d :0 --auto` has no effect. Here's my output:

```
$ xrandr -d :0
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02
   1152x864      75.00
   1024x768      75.08    60.00
   800x600       75.00    60.32
   640x480       75.00    60.00
   720x400       70.08
```

Help appreciated

Comment: Judging from the output `DVI-I-1 disconnected` the monitor seems to be disconnected ? Are You sure the cable it working ?

Comment: cable is fine @MichalPrzybylowicz